# Export multiple json files

Tags: php, mysql, json, foreach

I'm using wordpress with nextgen gallery, and i would like to get the images from a specific gallery id in a seperate JSON file. So far i have this code, but that just exports the images from the given ID (in this case; 7). I know there must be some kind of foreach function, but my javascript knowledge won't go that far.

Could someone help me with this one? The code i have so far:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","DB-NAME","DB-PASSWORD");
mysql_select_db("DB-NAME");

$result=mysql_query("SELECT filename FROM zs_ngg_pictures WHERE galleryid = '7' ORDER BY sortorder LIMIT 3");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$output[]=$row;
}

$fp = fopen('result.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($output));
fclose($fp);

echo json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you're trying to achieve you can simply get all the pictures, put them in a multidimensional array:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT filename, galleryid FROM zs_ngg_pictures ORDER BY sortorder");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $output[$row['galleryid']][] = $row['filename'];
}
```

and you have a PHP array like this (if you got two galleries with id 7 and 23):

```
array(
  7 => array('file7-1.jpg','file7-2.jpg','file7-3.jpg'),
  23 => array('file23-1.jpg','file23-2.jpg'),
);
```

so the `result.json` file will be like:

```
{ "7"  : ["file7-1.jpg", "file7-2.jpg", "file7-3.jpg"],
  "23" : ["file23-1.jpg", "file23-2.jpg"] }
```

---

If you want separate files for each `galleryid` you can then loop and save files with different names:

```
foreach($output as $gall_id => $gallery) {
  file_put_contents('result-'.$gall_id.'.json', json_encode($gallery));
}
```

and you'll have two files named `result-7.json` and `result-23.json`

Comment: Thanks Guglie, the bottom part was exactly what i needed. I now get a unique json file for each id. Thanks again!

Comment: I looked at that asnwer as well. Didn't test it, but by the looks of it outputs just a single json file...

Comment: @Koen yes, it's just to write less and cleaner code. I've updated the answer with  `file_put_contents`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing complicated `fopen()` stuff and `echo`:

```
$fp = fopen('result.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($output));
fclose($fp);

echo json_encode($output);
```

you can simply call:

```
file_put_contents('result.json', json_encode($output));
readfile('result.json');
```

or you skip the file and simple output the JSON:

```
echo json_encode($output));
```